# Is it possible to use a partitioned CosmosDB collection as the BotDataStore using botbuilder-azure extensions?

Tags: botframework, azure-cosmosdb

The default collection created by the [botbuilder-azure](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure) extensions is a non-partitioned fixed storage (capped at 10GB). I tried creating an unlimited partitioned collection manually, but then, the code throws a runtime exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation.
```

Comment: "the code throws a runtime exception" < which code?

Comment: Can reproduce the issue: configure DocumentDbBotDataStore with unlimited partitioned collection, and then send message to bot, which will throw that exception. It seems that [botbuilder azure extensions](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/DocumentDbBotDataStore.cs) not support unlimited partitioned collection.

Comment: @NicolasR, sorry for the lack of details. By "the code throws a runtime exception", I mean that even the [sample application](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/DocumentDb) throws that exception, if I pass a partitioned collection name in the `DocumentDbBotDataStore()` constructor. This restricts us to the 10 GB storage limitation of a non partitioned CosmosDB collection. Is there any workaround for this or any upcoming feature expected for this soon?

Comment: @NitinKallikat Please file an issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/issues/new

Comment: @EricDahlvang, done. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/issues/67